# Wordpress WP_Query

Tags: wordpress

I have code for my carousel in Wordpress

```
<?php 
    $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
     'category_name' => 'home-slider', 
     'posts_per_page' => 5  
    )); 
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : 
    $the_query->the_post();
?>
<div class="sl-slide">
 <?php the_post_thumbnail('large');?>
 <div class="sl-slide-inner">
 <?php the_title();?>
 <?php the_excerpt();?>
</div>
</div>
<?php 
endwhile; 
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

I display 5 post in carousel. I want basic If-else statment where for every page I create static variable. for instance:.

```
if (post == 1) {
 $aka = 7;
} else if (post == 2) {
 $aka = 8;
} else if (post == 3) {
 $aka = 9;
} .. and etc.
```

I can't figure it out how to implement it in WP, how to say which post is now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are in WP_Query while-loop, you can access current post by $post variable, which has standard post object.
Just don't forget to have following row before the loop:

```
<?php 
    global $post;
    $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
     'category_name' => 'home-slider', 
     'posts_per_page' => 5  
    )); 
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : 
    $the_query->the_post();
?>
<div class="sl-slide">
<?php
if ($post->ID == 1) {
 $aka = 7;
} else if ($post->ID == 2) {
 $aka = 8;
} else if ($post->ID == 3) {
 $aka = 9;
}
?>
 <?php the_post_thumbnail('large');?>
 <div class="sl-slide-inner">
 <?php the_title();?>
 <?php the_excerpt();?>
</div>
</div>
<?php 
endwhile; 
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: it identifies only first case. where to insert if else?